# Django add fields to createsuperuser command

Tags: python, django, database, django-orm

I have several database tables that I use in Django. Now I want to design everything around the database not in the Django ORM but in the rational style of my MySQL database. This includes multiple tables for different information. I have made a drawing of what I mean. I want the `createsuperuser` command to query once for the `user` table and once for the `residence` table.

This could then look like this:

```
C:\Users\Project>python manage.py createsuperuser
username: input
firstname: input
lastname: input
password: *****
country: input
city: input
street: input
```

[image]

## Edit

Is there maybe a way to change the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management

You can create django custom commands which will looks like:

python manage.py createsuperuser2 (or similar name)

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       username = input("username")
       .... (next params)


       user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, defaults={"blabla"}
       Residence.objects.create(user=user, next params....)
```

Comment: Is this really that easy? So I will try. Thank you

Comment: I think it should work, but where do I than have to like call this file?

Comment: if you have file  like app/management/commands/createsuperuser2.py
you just run  python manage.py createsuperuser2

Answer (score 2):

Just setup `REQUIRED_FIELDS` inside your User class. If you don't have custom user class, create `class User(AbstractUser)` but dont forget to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"` in `settings.py`

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["country","city","street"]
```